# A problem of open cover

Tags: general-topology, compactness

I am struggling with a problem related to a proof in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/electronic-communications-in-probability/volume-15/issue-none/The-measurability-of-hitting-times/10.1214/ECP.v15-1535.full).

This is the claim: *suppose $K_1,K_2,\dots$ is a countable collection of compact subsets of the interval $[0,t]$, with $t>0$ a given real number. Assume that $K_1\supseteq K_2\supseteq K_3\supseteq\cdots$ and that  $\bigcap_{n}K_n=\varnothing$. Then it must exist $n$ such that $K_n=\varnothing$.*

To prove it, the author says that, if  $K_n\neq \varnothing$ for all $n$ then the collection $\left\{K_n^c\right\}$ would be an open cover of $[0,t]$ without finite sub-cover, which is impossible because by the Heine-Cantor theorem $[0,t]$ is compact.

I understand very clearly that from $\bigcap_nK_n=\varnothing$ taking the complement  we get $\bigcup_nK_n^c=\mathbb{R}\supset [0,t]$ and, being $K_n$ closed and bounded, $K_n^c$ is open and so $\left\{K_n^c\right\}$ is clearly an open cover of $[0,t]$. I cannot prove that it does not admit a finite sub-cover. I guess one should use the property $K_1\supseteq K_2\supseteq K_3\supseteq\cdots$ which translates into $K_1^c\subseteq K_2^c\subseteq K_3^c\subseteq\cdots$ for the complement sets. Any idea on how to proceed?

Comment: I wouldn't proceed by contradiction when direct proof is easier. If $\bigcap_n K_n = \emptyset$, then from $\{K_n^c\}$ choose finite subcover of $[0, t]$. Without loss of generality it is $\{K_1^c, \ldots K_n^c\}$. Now you have that $K_n=\bigcap_{k=1}^n K_k = \emptyset$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let consider $X=[0,t]$ and $\bigcap_nK_n=\varnothing$ taking the complement  we get $\bigcup_nK_n^c=[0,t]$ where I forget about $\Bbb R$ and I consider $[0,t]$with the subspace topology, being $K_n$ closed and bounded, $K_n^c$ is open and so $\left\{K_n^c\right\}$ is clearly an open cover of $[0,t]$. Suppose by contradiction there is not $n$ such $K_n=\emptyset$. So $\bigcup_nK_n^c=[0,t]$ can not have open-finite sub-cover. If they had, let $\bigcup_FK_n^c=[0,t]$where F is a finite set. Let take $M=maxF$ the property $K_1\supseteq K_2\supseteq K_3\supseteq\cdots$ which translates into $K_1^c\subseteq K_2^c\subseteq K_3^c\subseteq\cdots$ shows that $\bigcup_FK_n^c=K_M^c=[0,t]$ and so $K_M=\emptyset$  $ \unicode{x21af}$. So there is n such $K_n=\emptyset$.